# Django- How do I get the content of a model thats related to another?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i'm creating a to-do app. How do I view the tasks linked to the board? Like I understand that the board needs to be the foreign key to task.

Here is my code so far:
**Models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Board")
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Task(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

```
def board_post_detail(request, board_id):
obj = get_object_or_404(Board, id=board_id)
context = {"object": obj}

return render(request, 'boards/board_post_detail.html', context)
```

**board_post_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object.name}}</h1>
<p>Created by {{object.admin.username  }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can query `Task` model by board

Comment: Do you have any good resources on querying?

Comment: You can refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: `board.task_set.all()` will give you all tasks with a FK to your board. You can specify `related_name` on a foreign key, to change the reverse query name. E.g, `board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')` will allow you to query as `board.tasks.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find what tasks correspond to a specific instance of the Board class, then you should just make a query filtering by the instance:

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Board, id=board_id)
Task.objects.filter(board=obj)
```